# How to Delete a Node in Neo4j using Cypher Graph Query Language?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to Delete this `Pessoa` node and its relations to others,

but I don't want to delete the other nodes.

[image: Node]

This node has a `Guid` ID property with value `c40f314f-0ecf-42e1-b44d-85b6d72f134a`

I tried

```
MATCH (n {ID: 'c40f314f-0ecf-42e1-b44d-85b6d72f134a'}) DELETE n;
```

But this ERROR appears:

> Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintValidationFailed: Cannot delete node<35>, because it still has relationships. To delete this node, you must first delete its relationships.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using

```
MATCH (n {ID: 'c40f314f-0ecf-42e1-b44d-85b6d72f134a'}) DETACH DELETE n;
```

> Deleted 1 node, deleted 2 relationships, completed after 2 ms.

Note that relationships of the node were removed as well.

Comment: Yep, nodes can't be deleted until their relationships are deleted (we don't allow hanging relationships in Neo4j), so `detach delete` is the way to go.

Comment: This is correct behaviour for DELETE. The DETACH DELETE means: "I know whan I am doing, delete the Node and all Relations."

Comment: Nice one, @Tony